# Remix + Vite logging error when importing from .server file

Tags: remix.run

I have a file named validation.server.jsx that i use to export a schema validation function.

As the name indicate it is a .server file with code to run exclusively server-side.

I than use the function exported the refered file to validate data inside the action of my route.jsx.

Now with Vite, Im getting the error below just by importing the function from the validation.server.jsx file into my app/routes/admin/route.jsx.

```
import { validateSchema } from "../../lib/validation.server"
```

By making this import I get the error or any import from a .server file into a route.jsx file i get the error:

```
Pre-transform error: Server-only module referenced by client
    '../../lib/validation.server' imported by route 'app/routes/admin/route.jsx'
  Remix automatically removes server-code from these exports:
    `loader`, `action`, `headers`
```

Remix version 2.8.1

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this one?

Comment: I did. I noticed that I was having this problem in just one route.  I don't know why that specific route raises this problem. Other routes worked fine. The solution for the problematic route was making the import inside the loader and action like this: export const action= async ({ request, context }) => {
   const { validateSchema } = await import('../../lib/validation.server');
... Also take a look into this question here: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/9035

Comment: Thanks! I also resolved this by moving the logic that was problematic to a separate .server file and import where needed.